# A problem concerning a set’s closed intersections implying closedness

Tags: general-topology

I have a feeling I didn’t quite get this problem from Munkres right. I’d like to proceed by contradiction, but feel like I’m missing some insight, which means I might be lying accidentally somewhere here. Comments would be greatly appreciated.

A set $A$ lies in $X$ with the property that all points $p$ in $X$ have a neighborhood $N$, such that $N \cap A$ is closed in $N$. Show this implies $A$ is closed in $X$

My attempt: Suppose, anticipating a contradiction, that A is open in X. We will show there exists $p\in X$ with no such neighborhood $N$ satisfying $A\cap N$ is closed in $N$.

If $A$ and $N$ are disjoint, $N\cap A= \emptyset$, which is closed and open, so we want a nonempty intersection.

All neighborhoods $N$ are open in $X$ (by defn), and the intersection of finite open sets on $X$ is an open set (a known theorem). Therefore, $N\cap A$ is open on $X$.

Then $N\cap A$ is open on $N$ as well, I think? This last part I’m pretty sure I can say, but I couldn’t go the other way, as in, open in $N$ does not imply open in $X$.

Comment: Hey! It's not true that a set which is not closed is the same as an open set. To start the proof by contradiction, you should consider $A$ as *not closed*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let x be a limit point of A, then theres a N like you said. N intersect A isn't empty, and x is also a limit point of N intersect A in N, so it's in A too. Hence A is closed.